# JavaScript - submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ink.sapo.pt

I'm trying to use a form validator from ink.sapo.pt http://ink.sapo.pt/index.php/js/ui#formvalidator

I want to intercept the submit event to write my own code but the following event is always called:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
   alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
});
```

even if the onsubmit attribute is false.

Basically I want ink.sapo.pt to validate my form but I want to use my own code every time the form is validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure java-script

```
<form id="myform" class="ink-form block" method="post" action="#" 
onsubmit="submitForm(this);">

function submitForm(formObj)
{
    if(SAPO.Ink.FormValidator.validate(formObj))
    {
          //Button Action
    }

}
```

Comment: you welcome & if you don't mind make vote up so other can identify clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
});
```

Basically, what the added line is doing is, as you can guess, avoiding the default behavior on the specified event.